# Magento 2 How can I restrict abc.com/newsletter/manage/?

Tags: magento2, customer, newsletter

In Magento 2 we have newsletter functionality and we can hide the link from the customer account and hide from customer account create a form as well. That all working fine.

I want to hide the page or restrict the page URL "newsletter/manage", How can I disable this URL or restrict this URL?

Is anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: using .htaccess you can do it

Comment: any another way? in the newsletter module, I found one "dispatch" action in newsletter controller @ "vendor\magento\module-newsletter\Controller\Manage.php" should we can use plugin here?

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch function runs before execute function in Magento controller.
So you can override this controller using preference and then you can return from contorller based on your condition in Dispatch function.

Comment: in Dispatch function, How we can use the URL redirection?

Comment: You can use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; class

Comment: one more thing I get "\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Index" here we can override execute method and redirect it. does it make sense?

Comment: Yes of course it should work.